# Qt/C++ regular expression library with unicode property support

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I'm converting an application from the .Net framework to Qt using C++. The application makes extensive use of [regular expression unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), i.e. `\p{L}, \p{M}`, etc. I've just discovered that the QRegExp class lacks support for this among other things (lookbehinds, etc.)

Can anyone recommend a C++ regular expression library that:

- Supports unicode properties
- Is unicode-aware in other respects (i.e. \w matches more than ASCII word characters)
- As a bonus, supports lookbehinds.

Please don't point me to the wikipedia article; I don't trust it. That article says that QRegExp supports unicode properties. Unless I'm really doing something wrong, it doesn't. I'm looking for someone actually using unicode properties with a regex library in a project.

Comment: Did you test all PatternSyntaxes? Remember that default QRegExp::PatternSyntax is QRegExp::RegExp, try it out with QRegExp::RegExp2, it's extended version of normal rx.

Comment: Yes, I tried both RegExp and RegExp2; no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://site.icu-project.org/

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of
>   **C/C++** and Java libraries providing
>   Unicode and Globalization support for
>   software applications.
>
> - released under a nonrestrictive open source license
> - ...
> - **Regular Expression:** ICU's regular expressions fully support Unicode
>     while providing very competitive
>     performance.

It's also compatible to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), see [their statement in this regard](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html).

Comment: Excellent; just what I was looking for. Works great, although I had a bear of a time getting it to compile and link on OS X! Thanks!

Comment: @Dave if you had trouble please file a bug. I do my main development on OSX and ICU is built into OSX.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing stopping you from using PCRE (http://www.pcre.org/), though converting back and forth from QStrings to const char *s could be a pain/performance hit.